# Question about row equivalent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am training for my exam, and I don't understand very well what does it means that two matrices are row equivalent. I understand that row equivalence mean that they have the same solution. But how this option I write are linked to the row equivalence. If there any of the statement that are true? If you can explain how they are related to row equivalence.

Thanks

1. If $A$ is invertible so $B$ invertible
2. if $Ax = 0$ has one solution $\implies$ $Bx = 0$ has one solution
3. $\text{det}A = \text{det}B$
4. $\text{rank A} = \text{rank} B$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a site that can substitute for regular study of a topic. If you [edit] your question to ask a particular question, show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: one matrix, two *matrices*

Comment: Can you prove that number $3$ implies the other statements?

Comment: I don't know. So I ask for help in order to understand

Comment: The section in your textbook on rank will likely start with a statement about row equivalence and will lead you to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain why is enough to prove statement number $3$. (At least when we are talking about square matrices, otherwise $det(A)$ has no meaning)

$3\implies 1$: A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is non-zero. If $A$ is invertible, we have $det(A)\neq 0$, using $3$, we get $det(B)\neq 0$ and hence $B$ is invertible.

$3\implies 2$: A matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if the only solution to the equation $Ax=0$ is $x=0$ . That is $1\iff 2$.

$3\implies 4$:  In general a $m×n$ matrix has rank $r$ if and only if some $r×r$ minor does not vanish and every $(r+1)×(r+1)$ minor does vanish. We already know that vanishing (having determinant equal to 0) is not chaged by row operations (we are assuming $3$) hence the rank of a matrix is also invariant.

Try to prove now that if two square matrices are row equivalent then they have the same determinant. If you can't prove it, tell me and I will add it to the answer later.